# How add new <li> element beetween two or more <li> elements using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<ul>` and `<li>` elements such these:

```
<ul>
<li>a element</li>
<li>b element</li>
<li>c element</li>
<li>d element</li>
<li>e element</li>
<li>f element</li>
</ul>
```

Than I want to add a new `<li>` element

```
<li>abc element</li>
```

beetween

```
<li>b element</li>
```

and

```
<li>c element</li>
```

For example:

```
<ul>
<li>a element</li>
<li>b element</li>
<li>abc element</li>
<li>c element</li>
<li>d element</li>
<li>e element</li>
<li>f element</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this (if it's possible)?

Comment: Hint: http://api.jquery.com/after/. You'll have to try it for yourself first

Comment: what part of your code is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').after('<li >abc element</li>');
```

Where in `nth-child()` you can specify after which child you want `li` to be inserted

Here with `nth-child(2)` will be added after the **second** `li` as you want in your example

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NayY7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can select specific items in a list with the eq method in jQuery.

```
$('ul li').eq(1).after("<li>abc element</li>")
```

Remember that eq is zero-based, so the first element is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. This will descent from `ul` element until the second child of `li`

```
$(function(){
 $("ul li:nth-child(2)").append( "<li>abc element</li>" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These sites may come in handy when trying to select things:

- [Jquery Selectors (jQuery API)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Jquery Selectors (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

For the rest I'd recommend playing around yourself untill you have got what you want. That way you learn more yourself as well.

Hope it helps!

Also, don't forget to include a jQuery file in your website if you use jQuery!